# C# WPF Agregar valor default a todos los combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola lo que quiero lograr es que en todos mis combobox aparezca un valor default (seleccionar), pero no lo eh logrado.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListaRegimenPagos, Converter={StaticResource FormatoComboBox}}"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Asesor.RegimenPago.RegimenPagoID}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Asesor.RegimenPago, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          SelectedValuePath="RegimenPagoID"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion"/>
```

Había echo algo así, pero al momento de seleccionar el ítem me sale error de conversión porque el combobox tiene ComboBoxPairs y el selectedItem tiene otro tipo

```
public class ComboBoxPairs {

        /// <summary>
        ///     LLave del valor
        /// </summary>
        public string Key { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Valor de combobox
        ///     (Valor que se ve en pantall)
        /// </summary>
        public string Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Descripcion
        /// </summary>
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        ///     Tooltip del combobox
        /// </summary>
        public string ToolTip { get; set; }

        public ComboBoxPairs() { }
        public ComboBoxPairs(string key, string value) {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }

    }
```

---

```
 /// <summary>
    ///     Interfaz para ComboBox
    /// </summary>
    public interface IComboBoxPairs {
        ComboBoxPairs ToComboBoxPairs();
    }
```

---

```
  public class ListToComboBoxPair : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {

            if (value != null) {

                if (value is IEnumerable<object> list) {

                    List<ComboBoxPairs> CB = new List<ComboBoxPairs> {
                        new ComboBoxPairs("", "")
                    };

                    foreach (var item in list) {
                        CB.Add(((IComboBoxPairs)item).ToComboBoxPairs());
                    }

                    return CB;
                }

            }

            return null;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funcionó poner un valor por defecto de la siguiente forma.

combobox.Items.Insert(0;"Seleccionar");
combobox.SelectdIndex=0;

Answer (score 0):

Mira, para que un `Combobox` tenga "*Seleccionar*" como "*valor por defecto*" tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<ComboBox IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Seleccionar"/>
```

Es necesario que incluyas las etiquetas `IsReadOnly` y `IsEditable`, ambas en `True`, y luego el `Text` será tu "*valor por defecto*", esta es la manera de lograrlo, una vez se expande aparecerán los valores reales, ya que poner texto en el índice 0 no es correcto.